# Cannot find the requested object when attempting to load new X509 Certificate

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, identityserver3

I'm just walking through the IdentityServer 3 official tutorials and I'm on the MVC app tutorial (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html) but I've hit a roadblock. on the section 'Adding Startup' it gets you to download a certificate to use in the application, but I can't get this to work.

The sample code that is failing locally is:

```
X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            string.Format(@"{0}\bin\identityServer\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
    }
```

But despite the certificate being in this location, I get an error. I've even tried copying the certificate to the temp folder so I know the path is good,

```
X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
        {
            return new X509Certificate2("c:\\temp\\idsrv3test.pfx", "idsrv3test");
        }
```

but it still fails with the same message:

```
Cannot find the requested object.

  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.


Source Error: 



Line 33:         X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
Line 34:         {
Line 35:             return new X509Certificate2("c:\\temp\\idsrv3test.pfx", "idsrv3test");
Line 36:         }
Line 37:     }
```

Stack trace:

```
[CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr) +36
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertBlobType(Byte[] rawData) +0
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +66
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password) +109
   is3_mvc.Startup.LoadCertificate() in C:\scratch\.net\IdentityServer3\is3-mvc\is3-mvc\Startup.cs:59
   is3_mvc.Startup.<Configuration>b__4_0(IAppBuilder idsrvApp) in C:\scratch\.net\IdentityServer3\is3-mvc\is3-mvc\Startup.cs:25
   Owin.MapExtensions.Map(IAppBuilder app, PathString pathMatch, Action`1 configuration) +178
   Owin.MapExtensions.Map(IAppBuilder app, String pathMatch, Action`1 configuration) +108
   is3_mvc.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in C:\scratch\.net\IdentityServer3\is3-mvc\is3-mvc\Startup.cs:23

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +160
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +66
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +123
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeBlueprint>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +71
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +462
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

I've also tried loading the cert using a different approach:

```
var stx = File.Open(@"c:\temp\idsrv3test.pfx", FileMode.Open);
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stx))
            {
                return new X509Certificate2(br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length), "idsrv3test");
            }
```

But this gives exactly the same error, so I dont think its a problem loading the file per se.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Seems others have had similar problems on SO before, but no exact solution has been posted that matches the above.

I'm guessing its not the actual locating of the file that is the problem here but something else, but I dont know what that could be...

Thanks

Comment: Can you read the file with File.ReadAllBytes()?  If yes, does passing those bytes instead of the filename produce the same exception?  There are some filesystem objects (like symlinks) that the by-filename constructor can't read, but if you get the bytes yourself it's usually happy (unless the bytes aren't a real/valid certificate)

Comment: Have you tried manual download of the file as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195431/identityserver3-x509certificate2-constructor-error-cannot-find-requested-obj?rq=1)?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than new X509Certificate2 file that is using

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Certificates\cert.pem");
```

use X509Certificate2 function methods. example

```
X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(@"C:\Certificates\cert.pem");
```

There are other inbuilt static methods for instantiating certificates. Check them out in metadata
[image]